# Visual Studio Code 0.9.1 TypeScript Watch Configuration

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I just want to mirror what WebStorm does - compile the TS file upon saving with a passed configuration. I see the tsconfig.json and new isWatching task configuration, but it doesnt work without Ctrl+Shift+B.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use just [build-in watch mode](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options) of typescript itself?
If you have `tsconfig.json` just run `tsc -p . --watch` in console in your project folder.

Basically it is similar feature as WebStorm's - but WebStorm has console view which is missing in VS Code (AFAIK).

Comment: Thank you andrej, I use grunt watch to do my ts compilation, that isn't really the issue - I want to get rid of the red underlines and get the clean transpiler with each save in the IDE. I onboard lots of devs and they struggle seeing the red, and I am trying to teach them to do ctrl+shift+b each time to get rid of it.